# Deezer API: nbTracks/total not reliable?

Tags: api, deezer

I'm implementing an application based on the [Deezer API](https://developers.deezer.com/api) but something looks fishy from what I see with the playlist track count.

https://api.deezer.com/playlist/152068711
Displays the playlist information. You can see 2 things from here, the nb_tracks is **399**, and the tracks/data is counting **215** elements.

https://api.deezer.com/playlist/152068711/tracks
Here, it's supposed to give us the tracks, you can see a total of **221** (tracks only contains 25 elements, I presume the default value for pagination)

https://api.deezer.com/playlist/152068711/tracks?index=100&limit=1000
total= **218**

https://api.deezer.com/playlist/152068711/tracks?index=215&limit=10
total= **222**

And so on, despite the same checksum, the 'total' field isn't the same all the time, most of the time it doesn't match the real track count, and it never equals the playlist.nb_tracks ...

Is this API buggy or did I miss something?

(to be honest, the documentation is not very detailed)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a know issue.
The best way to use the API is to use pagination with a larger range.

Comment: I figured it's maybe better to use directly the *next* url instead of relying on counts... but it's clearly not optimal for fluid lazy-loading.